# TypeScript decorators, get type of value

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

Here is my code.

```
function observableDecorator<T>(target: T, key: keyof T) {
    let observable = ko.observable<any>((target[key] as any));

    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        get() {
            this[key]._ko_util_id = random;
            this.obs = observable<
                HERE_IS_WERE_THE_TYPE_OF_VALUE_SHOULD_BE
            >();
        },
        set(value) {
            observable(value);
        }
    });
}
```

On line 6 I want the type of value. I tried to get the type from `target[key]`, but it's undefined. I'll make sure to like and mark the correct answer.

Comment: Why are you setting something in a getter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=32#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-nQ0W41gyxW4NXaw2mxMgA) is what you're looking for, but it seems like it might do what you want.

```
function observableDecorator<
    T extends Record<string, any>,
    K extends keyof T,
    V = T extends Record<string, infer X> ? X : never
>(target: T, key: K) {
    const observable = ko.observable<V>(target[key]);

    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        get() {
            this[key]._ko_util_id = random;
            this.obs = observable<V>(); // or typeof random?
        },
        set(value: V) {
            observable(value);
        }
    });
}
```